# Why isn't redundant to indicate which variables are held constant in thermodynamical partial derivatives?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

From a calculus-point of view,  indicating what variables are constant in  a partial derivative  is implicit in the definition of partial derivatives. In calculus when we perform partial derivaties of functions of several variables, we don't need to indicate the other variables are being held constant, we know that is the way to do partial derivatives. So why is it not the case in Thermodynamics?

Comment: Look up 'maxwells relations'

Comment: It might be intutively more instructive to recall that $\partial/\partial x$ measures the change due to a variation in $x$ while keeping *all other* variables constant. Hence, it's in some sense more important to know what you keep constant, because that already fixes $x$ to quite some extent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always need to specify what is held constant, both in thermodynamics and in calculus class. (Sometimes this is obvious, e.g. for a long derivation involving fields exclusively in Cartesian coordinates, a derivative with respect to $x$ always holds $y$ and $z$ constant. In these cases the specification is implicit, but it's not obvious in general.)

Here's a completely trivial example: let $f(x, y) = x + y$. Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigg|_{y} = 1.$$
Let $z = 2x + y$. Then we can change variables in the same function to get $f(x, z) = z - x$, so
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \bigg|_{z} = -1.$$
So you need to say whether it's $y$ or $z$ being kept the same. This is the kind of issue that is omnipresent in thermodynamics.

Comment: In calculus no one writes the line saying the other variables are constant, that is like super implicit. I don't see how the answer could change if not saying anything. In the second example , as instance , there is no x present so z is supposed to be constant, it wouldn't be a partial derivative if it weren't. What  am I missing?

Comment: Can you recomend a book which looks at this the way you are describing it?

Comment: @mathlover I'm not aware of any books that don't do it this way. As an example you can look at MIT OCW's completely standard 18.02 course.

Comment: Sorry, but all this is just nonsensically confusing notation. You might as well try to argue that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ are both the same function, because they are both called $f$. Just write $\partial f(x,y)/\partial x$ and $\partial f(x,z)/\partial x$ and "specifying which variables are held constant" is no longer necessary.

Comment: @alephzero That's just another standard way of notating the exact same thing. Writing $\partial f(x, y) / \partial x$ is exactly the same thing as writing $\partial f / \partial x |_y$. You can choose either one, but in both cases you need something that indicates what you hold constant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112931/discussion-on-answer-by-knzhou-why-isnt-redundant-to-indicate-which-variables-a). I have kept some of the comments around as there seems to be disagreement over the notation, but any further discussion should happen elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW @knzhou, this is exactly how I learned calculus also, and also how we learned to write things in thermodynamics... perhaps there is a different approach in different parts of the world?